# What's the meaning of hash sign (#) in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

In SPARQL, I often see usage of # at the end of prefix definitions, like this:

```
@prefix dt:   <http://example.org/datatype#>
```

What's the purpose? I couldn't find this in the SPARQL documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example seems to be in [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/), as in SPARQL the syntax would be:

```
PREFIX dt: <http://example.org/datatype#>
```

But it’s the same idea: Instead of having to use full IRIs in your query, you can use [prefixed names](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames):

1. In your example, the *prefix label* is `dt`. It’s mapped to the IRI `http://example.org/datatype#`.
2. In your query, it might get used as `dt:foobar`, where `foobar` is called the *local part*.
3. The mapped IRI from the *prefix label* and the *local part* get concatenated to form the "actual" IRI:

   `http://example.org/datatype#` + `foobar` =
   `http://example.org/datatype#foobar`
4. (Instead of using `dt:foobar`, you could also use `<http://example.org/datatype#foobar>`.)

So the `#` just happens to be part of the IRI design. It’s a popular way to structure vocabulary IRIs in the Semantic Web. The other popular way is using a `/`. See [HashVsSlash](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HashVsSlash).